# Connecting to a mysql db using RoR 3, sqlite3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Surely this is a newb question as I am just learning RoR and can't find a simple answer to this relatively simple need.

I want to use sqlite3 as my app's database, but I would like to connect to another mysql database just to return data.

I've tried to install the gem for mysql, but won't install for whatever reason. I tried to use MAMP mysql lib but it rejected that as well.

Using:
 - rails 3
 - ruby 1.9
 - mac os x snow leopard

Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: could work if you do `sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/Mamp/Library/bin/mysql_config`  when you install the mysql gem

Comment: Sadly, that did not work. It was my first guess as well, but the end result is: mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.

Comment: I ended up downloading the latest mysql as a .dmg and installed it. I then did `sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` and the gem installed successfully. Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the gem [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2); in their readme, the section entitled "Usage" may be really helpful for you.

Comment: The "Usage" describes precisely what I wish to accomplish. Now if I can get the gem installed, we're gold :)

Comment: Just add it to your gemfile like this: `gem 'mysql2'` and then run a `bundle install`. Alternatively you could also install it using `gem install mysql2`

When I installed it I had errors I had to fix - let me know what you get.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The result is: Installing mysql2 (0.2.6) with native extensions /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no

Comment: Do you have mysql installed on your machine? Try to go to terminal and type `mysql`. If you need to install mysql for your mac it may be found here http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads